# How to dynamically transform a Java Interface to make its return type wrapped in Futures?

Tags: java, reflection

Given the following interface:

```java
interface DummyAPI {
  int f1(int x);
  String f2();
}
```

What I want is a way to write a class like this:

```java
class Futurized<T> {
}
```

where effectively, the methods of `Futurized<DummyAPI>` would effectively be:

```java
    Future<Integer> f1(int x);
    Future<String> f2();
```

Comment: No magical way to do it, just declare that interface explicitly.

Comment: You could look into Java annotation processors - these are basically plugins to the Java compiler and they could generate new source code (the new version of the interface with `Future` return types) based on your interface automatically, if you mark your interface with an annotation.

Comment: Everything is possible, but lets starts from: why you want to do this, what exactly you want to achieve. In general if you want to have code that works both in sync i async way, write it just in async way, as then it is easy to run in sync anyways.